# ignore ipv6 router advertisements for static addresses with bonded interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I need to attribute static IPv6 addresses (not use autoconfigured addresses, and ignore router  advertisements).
This can be done as follows for a standard interface like eth0

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address myprefix:mysubnet::myip
  gateway myprefix:mysubnet::mygatewayip
 netmask 64
 pre-up /sbin/sysctl -q -w net.ipv6.conf.$IFACE.autoconf=0
 pre-up /sbin/sysctl -q -w net.ipv6.conf.$IFACE.accept_ra=0
```

However, how can this be done for bonded interfaces? 
using the "all" interface does not work.

System is Ubuntu 10.04, 2.6.24-24-server.
(12.04 seems to be the same).

If one uses the above sysctl command for the bond0, the networking hangs on boot, because /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/bond0 does not yet exist and cannot be written to.

Once the system has booted /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/bond0 exists, so one solution after booting is to add the following to /etc/rc.local:

```
 /sbin/sysctl -q -w net.ipv6.conf.bond0.autoconf=0
 /sbin/sysctl -q -w net.ipv6.conf.bond0.accept_ra=0
 /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

and this has the desired effect, the autoconfig v6 address disappears.
Seems like a bit of a hack though, are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
iface bond0 inet6 static
    address myprefix:mysubnet::myip
    gateway myprefix:mysubnet::mygatewayip
    netmask 64

    post-up /sbin/sysctl -q -w net.ipv6.conf.bond0.autoconf=0
    post-up /sbin/sysctl -q -w net.ipv6.conf.bond0.accept_ra=0
```

If that does not work, I'd probably try it with a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`